# Disable the box drawn around words

Tags: atom-editor

My Atom editor draws a box around some words such as `devtools`. How do I stop this behavior? The other weird thing it does is italicize the word `REVIEW` whenever I type it. But just this word *REVIEW*. How do I turn off this auto feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDIT from me] - Close your "find" pane.